# Whys is this call ambiguous?

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

In the following code, why is the call to `bar(std::shared_ptr<B>)` ambiguous, but `bar(std::shared_ptr<A>)` is not?

The intent of `foo` is to treat const and non-const pointers differently. Can I disambiguate this in any other way than changing the call site to `bar(std::dynamic_pointer_cast<A>(b))`?

```
#include <memory>

struct A {};
struct B : A {};


void foo(std::shared_ptr<const A>) { }
void foo(std::shared_ptr<A>) { }

void bar(const A &) { }
void bar(A &) { }

int main() {
    A a;
    bar(a); // ok

    B b;
    bar(b); // ok

    auto ap = std::make_shared<A>();
    foo(ap); // ok

    auto bp = std::make_shared<B>();
    foo(bp); // ambiguous

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: A `void foo(std::shared_ptr<A>)` is passing shared *ownership* to the foo routine.  If the intent is to pass shared ownership, then that is the right thing to do.  If passing ownership is *not* the intent, then the parameter ought to be `A` or `A*`or `A const*` or `A&` or `A const&`.

Answer (score 1):

The call is ambiguous as a `std::shared_ptr<B>` is not a const or non const shared pointer of type A.

As this, it would use an implicit cast operation from `std::shared_ptr<B>` to `std::shared_ptr<A>` or `std::shared_ptr<const A>`. These both options are ambiguous as you always can cast from non const to const.

If you have:

```
auto bp = std::make_shared<const B>();
foo(bp);
```

it is not longer ambiguous as a `const B` can only be casted to `const A` in this case.

As the implicit cast is ambiguous, you have to use an explicit one in your given scenario.

As a hack you can write some helper template which automatically detects if the given pointer is const or not and pass it with an explicit cast automatically.

```
template < typename T>  
void foo( std::shared_ptr<T>& ptr)
{
    foo( std::static_pointer_cast<A>(ptr) );
}

template < typename T>  
void foo( std::shared_ptr<const T>& ptr)
{
    foo( std::static_pointer_cast<const A>(ptr) );
}
```

Now you can use it like:

```
    auto bp = std::make_shared<B>();
    foo(bp); 
    auto bp2 = std::make_shared<const B>();
    foo(bp2);
```